# Moving a Flask service to Python3 has increased the response time

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application that used to run python 2.7 and it's average response time was 10ms
after an upgrade to python3.7, the average response time increased to **40ms!**
I have a new relic monitoring, but it's not enough to know what **line in the cod**e is causing this delay

here are my dependencies

```
aniso8601==1.0.0
boto==2.39.0
cffi==1.12.0
colander==1.4.0
cryptography==2.3
enum34==1.1.6
Flask-RESTful==0.3.4
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
Flask==0.10.1
funcsigs==0.4
idna==2.8
ipaddress==1.0.22
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
python 3.7.2
mongoengine==0.18.2
newrelic==5.4.1.134
pbr==1.7.0
pyasn1==0.1.8
pycparser==2.19
pycrypto==2.6.1
pymongo==3.7.2
pyOpenSSL==17.3.0
pytz==2015.4
requests==2.5.1
six==1.12.0
webargs==0.15.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.1
Flask-Cors>=3.0.6,<3.1.0
flask-mongoengine==0.9.3
pymongo[tls,srv]==3.7.2
nose==1.3.4 # for dockerized tests run
# used for testing. HTTP client for python 3
urllib3==1.25.3
```

[image: after deploy]

stack trace [image: stack trace timing]

Comment: Do you use a real WSGI server (e.g. gunicorn, uwsgi) or `flask run`?

Comment: using supervisord to run this command `venv/bin/uwsgi --die-on-term --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/webservice.ini`

Answer (score 0):

No point in guessing, time to get to know [Python profiling tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html). Profile the same code running on Py2 and Py3 and you will know.

Comment: do you have a code example for profiling flask application? tried from  `ProfilerMiddleware` here https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-debugging-testing-and-profiling

Comment: I usually just wire [Werkzeug profiling middleware](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/middleware/profiler/#module-werkzeug.middleware.profiler).